# Very confusing, translate animation not completing if called too soon after previous call

Tags: android, animation

**SOLVED see below**

I have have an animation like a progress bar. I have a hardware footpedal that I use to start this animation. The expected result is:
Foot goes down and progress is increased until foot is released.
If I keep foot down progress goes from 0 to 100% animation distance (width of screen)
Next time I do it the same applies.
However:
If I release my foot BEFORE the animation has completed (say at 20%) then the next time I depress and hold the pedal the animation will NOT run all the way to the end and will stop at approximately 80% (As far as I can tell there is a relationship between the two but it might just be lack of sleep!) 
ALSO: If I wait a few seconds after holding the pedal for the shortened time (20%) then the next animation will run all the way as intended. I've posted code below.

Any idea what's happening? I'm on Samsung Galaxy S on Gingerbread.

```
public void startPedalProgress(int color){
    pedal_down_progress.setBackgroundColor(color);
    pedal_down_progress.clearAnimation();
    Animation progressAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pedal_progress);
    progressAnim.setDuration(3000);
    pedal_down_progress.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    pedal_down_progress.startAnimation(progressAnim);
}
public void stopPedalProgress(){
    pedal_down_progress.clearAnimation();
}
```

and my Animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
   android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
   android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
   android:duration="3000" />
</set>
```

I've tried declaring `progressAnim`as a global and calling `progressAnim.cancel()`...still exactly the same results. I've also tried using dynamically created animations.

Answer (score 0):

Aargh!, apologies everyone.
I finally realised what I was doing wrong!
I had a timer task set to cancel the animation with the same delay as the animation but I was forgetting to cancel this on a footpedal release.
Many thanks.
J